# Cors issue when rest api application server(express) and Angulars js application running on different port

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

I have rest api application written in node.js & express is running on port 3000 and angularjs application running on port 9001 on  same server . On calling rst api from angularjs application it is giving cors issue .

In rest api application  , I have used "cors" module

```
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

But it is giving me following error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/user/login. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS
```

Request header  and response header is as follow

**Response header**

```
Content-Length 222
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
Date Tue, 16 Dec 2014 08:40:05 GMT
X-Powered-By Express
```

view source

**Request Header**

```
Accept application/json, text/plain, /
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Authorization null
Content-Length 47
Content-Type application/json;charset=utf-8
Host localhost:3000
Origin http://localhost:9001
Referer http://localhost:9001/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry my mistake  , I haven't type correctly it here. In my code it is app.use(cors());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding adding line  **app.options('*', cors());** just before all routes.

It was an issue of preflight request with http-request-header "OPTIONS"

Answer (score -1):

You can set the solution to be

```
app.configure('development', function(){
    app.set('origins', '*:*');
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in [the documentation](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors#usage) about that, citation?

Comment: It's not about the documentation, its the normal scenario how we enable the cross origin policy for all the domains using this solution.