# CORS issue with node rest api and angularJS app on 2 ports

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, rest, cors

I have the classical CORS issue with my angularJS app (on localhost:9000) trying to catch my node server (on localhost:9001)

Here my rest api (app.js) code :

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // CORS headers
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',    'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(200);
        res.write("Allow: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        res.end();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

As you can see, i've tried those solutions in vain :

- [CORS in Node.js and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882106/cors-in-node-js-and-angularjs)
- [Cors issue when rest api application server(express) and Angulars js application running on different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499872/cors-issue-when-rest-api-application-serverexpress-and-angulars-js-application)

And here's the simple $http call in webapp :

```
var req = {
    method: 'GET',
        url: 'localhost:9001/memories'
    };
    $http(req).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            reutrnStatus.success = true;
            reutrnStatus.msg = status;
            memories = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            reutrnStatus.success = false;
            reutrnStatus.msg = status;
        });
```

I tried some solutions in webapp too (in app.js) :

```
// Enable AngularJS to send its requests with the appropriate CORS headers
// globally for the whole app:
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    /**
     * Just setting useXDomain to true is not enough. AJAX request are also
     * send with the X-Requested-With header, which indicate them as being
     * AJAX. Removing the header is necessary, so the server is not
     * rejecting the incoming request.
     **/
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

But i'm close to give up because it's still not working... That's giving me this same error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:9001/memories. Cross origin
requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, 
chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

And just to be fully clear, i followed that tutorial for the rest api :

- https://blog.jixee.me/how-to-write-an-api-in-one-week-part-2/

Comment: Why is the error in localhost:9001 when your server should be running on localhost:9000 (as you stated in your question). Are you sure the call should be going towards localhost:9000, which is your server side API?

Comment: You right it's my app on 9000 and the rest api on 9001 ;)

Comment: And are you sure you are visiting your angular app via localhost and not `file://`protocol? it looks like the page that is doing the ajax call, is not on `http://` or any of the given protocols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making a request to an unknown protocol.

`Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

You need to change this:

```
method: 'GET',
    url: 'localhost:9001/memories'
};
```

...to this:

```
method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:9001/memories'
};
```

Alternatively, you could set it to `//localhost:9001/memories` and the browser will use the current protocol which is useful if you're serving resources over both `http` and `https`.

*Although unrelated, your callbacks have typos in the variable names.*